# Release space in the string pool

Tags: luatex, tex-core

I managed to get a capacity exceeded message by adding a bit too many named coordinates to a number of tikzpictures and so started to test and now wonder if it is possible to release unneeded space in the string pool.

As an example: The following document creates quite a number of (local!) definitions and dies with pdflatex (TL2016) with the message

```
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [pool size=6136953].
\__prg_map_2:w ...sname test#1_17156_tl\endcsname
```

It dies with lualatex with the message

```
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [number of strings=495118].
<recently read> \__int_eval_end: 

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}

\begin{document}
bb
\ExplSyntaxOn

\int_step_inline:nnnn { 1 } { 1 } {20000}
 {
  \group_begin:
  \int_step_inline:nnnn { 1 } { 1 } {25}
  {
   \expandafter\def\csname test##1_#1_tl\endcsname{}
  }
  \group_end:
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\end{document}
```

Would it be possible to release the space used by the local definitions and decrease the number of strings after the end of the group? Or is there a way to create really local definitions?

**Attention** I'm not asking how to enlarge the pool size. I know how to do it.

Comment: space can be recaptured in the string pool, as i understand it, only if it was the most recent space assigned.  that is one of the reasons why it can "run out" by opening too many files -- something almost always touches the pool when a file is read in, so the file name is "frozen" there.  let me see if i can find a reference.

Comment: Ah, the `\csname`-in-a-group issue :-) Not sure there is a solution, but it is an 'interesting' one isn't it!

Comment: @JosephWright: It is not only \csname (in case you mean commands build with `\csname`), `\def\XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX{}` fills the pool too, but it much more difficult to overflow it with "normal definitions" than by using \csname and loops.

Comment: the section in `tex.web` regarding the string pool contains the sentence "To destroy the most recently made string, we say |flush_string|."  there is no other "cleaning" function in the original program.  don't know if the lua gang figured out how to do it.  (is this an answer?)

Comment: line number in tex.web (Version 3.14159265, January 2014): 1201.

Comment: for pdftex you can increase the pool size in texmf.cnf but for luatex this isn't supposed to happen (although I can confirn it does with texlive 2016) , the manual says: The input line buffer and pool size are now also reallocated when needed, and the texmf.cnf settings buf_size and pool_size are silently ignored.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Regarding luatex I guess that "number of strings " is not "pool size".

Comment: @UlrikeFischer well whatever it's called it's not being "reallocated when needed" :-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle What I meant, is that "number of strings" is  perhaps a different register than pool size ("characters in strings"). Looking at the manual the status library has beside `pool_size` a `max_strings` and `str_ptr` field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Would it be possible to release the space used by the local definitions and decrease the number of strings after the end of the group?

Answers are already given in the comments :-).

Answer for standard TeX.web: NO, created string entries and the characters for the string in the string pool are never released after they are created.  There is only a small optimization possible for the last created string.  Thus either the "maximum number of strings" or the "string pool" will overflow depending on the constants in the TeX.web change file.

Answer for LuaTeX (Status January 2023): NO, because in principle the LuaTeX code uses the same code as in TeX.web.  The constants for the pool size and the maximum number of strings are enlarged to huge constants, but they are still constants and strings and the reserved characters for strings are never released.  (See ["source/texk/web2c/luatexdir/tex/stringpool.h"](https://github.com/TeX-Live/luatex/blob/trunk/source/texk/web2c/luatexdir/tex/stringpool.h) for the LuaTeX constants and ["source/texk/web2c/luatexdir/tex/stringpool.c"](https://github.com/TeX-Live/luatex/blob/trunk/source/texk/web2c/luatexdir/tex/stringpool.c) for the code with the description in the comment.)

> Or is there a way to create really local definitions?

No, if you create local csnames and if these csnames have totally different "names".
In all these cases they will allocate a new string and allocate characters for the string in the string pool.

You can try to minimize the impact by using always the same set of csnames in all local groups.

Or you implement a different way how to reference your "named coordinates" to a reasonable number.

(Or someone re-implements the TeX string pool functions in a completely different way in the LuaTeX code to allocate and release LuaTeX internal strings in a more dynamic way.  This will be a bigger effort with more side effects to the table of equivalents etc.  And if some user will assign global defined "named coordinates" you will have the same problem again, because you can't release the strings for the globally defined csnames when the local group closes.)

Comment: nice summary of the comments ;-)