# Create a fake label ref using list

Tags: macros, lists, expl3, xparse, grouping

Hello everyone once again, after having resolved my doubt regarding the use of `\label` and `\ref`. Reading the comments, I have noticed that in many occasions do not need to use the referencing system, only the values associated with these.

My idea is not to use auxiliary files (need many files en some cases, append mode in `.aux` file no exist in TeX), save in memory list short answers to exercises , so when copying and pasting from one file to another not need to make major modifications (changue only a ref to list).

This is the file (which works)

```
% !file: test.tex
% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass{article}%
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{many}
\usepackage{pgffor}

% Set key for multicols in enumitem
\SetEnumitemKey{columns}{before=\begin{multicols}{#1},after=\end{multicols}}%

% Some definition
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{exercise}[theorem]{Exercise}

% from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/215571/7832
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\storedata}{mm}
  {
   \bcp_store_data:nn { #1 } { #2 }
  }

\NewDocumentCommand{\appenddata}{mm}
 {
  \bcp_append_data:nn { #1 } { #2 }
 }

\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand{\getdata}{O{1}m}
 {
  \bcp_get_data:nn { #1 } { #2 }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \bcp_store_data:nn #1 #2
 {
  % create the sequence if it doesn't exist or clear it if it exists
  \seq_if_exist:cTF { l_bcp_data_#1_seq }
   { \seq_new:c { l_bcp_data_#1_seq } }
   { \seq_clear:c { l_bcp_data_#1_seq } }
  % append the items
  \__bcp_append_data:nn { #1 } { #2 }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \bcp_append_data:nn #1 #2
 {
  % create the sequence if it doesn't exist, do nothing if it exists
  \seq_if_exist:cF { l_bcp_data_#1_seq }
   { \seq_new:c { l_bcp_data_#1_seq } }
  % append the items
  \__bcp_append_data:nn { #1 } { #2 }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \__bcp_append_data:nn #1 #2
 {
  % append items one at a time
  \tl_map_inline:nn { #2 }
   {
    \seq_put_right:cn { l_bcp_data_#1_seq } { ##1 }
   }
 }

\cs_new:Npn \bcp_get_data:nn #1 #2
 {
  % retrieve the requested item
  \seq_item:cn { l_bcp_data_#2_seq } { #1 }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\section{Exercices}

\begin{exercise}
Factoring next expression:
\end{exercise}

\begin{enumerate}
\item $a^{2}-b^{2}$
\item $x^{2}-2x+1$ 
\item $3x+3y+3z$
\item $3x+3y-6z$
\end{enumerate}
% save in list exe:1
\appenddata{exe:1}{{$\left(a-b\right)\left(a+b\right)$}}
\appenddata{exe:1}{{$\left(x-1\right)^{2}$}}
\appenddata{exe:1}{{$3x+3y+3z$}}
\appenddata{exe:1}{{$3\left(x+y-2z\right)$}}

\begin{exercise}
Solve:
\end{exercise}
\begin{enumerate}
\item $2x+3=5$
\item $5x-2=7$
\item $4-3x=5$
\end{enumerate}

% save in list exe:2
\appenddata{exe:2}{{$1$}}
\appenddata{exe:2}{{$\dfrac{9}{5}$}}
\appenddata{exe:2}{{$-\dfrac{1}{3}$}}

\section{Answer}
% #1 : pass to tcolorbox
% #2 : name
% #3 : list
% #4 : maxvalue
% #5 : columns
\DeclareTotalTColorBox{\answer}{O{} m m m O{4}}
{ colback=white,size=small,top=0mm,bottom=1.5mm, left=0mm,width=\columnwidth,title filled,%
  fontupper=\small,fonttitle=\small\sffamily,%
    adjusted title={#2},center title,#1}
  {% 
  \begin{enumerate}[columns=#5,leftmargin=15pt,labelsep=3pt,font=\footnotesize,nosep,widest=25,]%
  \small
  \setlength{\columnsep}{0pt} 
   \foreach \x in {1,...,#4} {
    \item \getdata[\x]{#3}%
    }
  \end{enumerate}
  }%
\answer{Exercise 1}{exe:1}{4}
\answer{Exercise 2}{exe:2}{3}[3]
\end{document}
```

Now comes my problem, the macro I take from [Storing an array of strings in a command](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/215571/7832) only works in local mode, if write it inside an environment it only exists in this and not outside it, that is, I will not be able to access it outside the environment. For example:

```
% save list in enumerate 
\begin{enumerate}
\item $a^{2}-b^{2}$ \appenddata{exe:1}{{$\left(a-b\right)\left(a+b\right)$}}
\item $x^{2}-2x+1$ \appenddata{exe:1}{{$\left(x-1\right)^{2}$}}
\item $3x+3y+3z$ \appenddata{exe:1}{{$3x+3y+3z$}}
\item $3x+3y-6z$ \appenddata{exe:1}{{$3\left(x+y-2z\right)$}}
\end{enumerate}
```

And my idea is that it works within enumerate environments, and then access values outside of them. I have tried with this:

```
% !file: test.tex
% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass{article}%
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{many}
\usepackage{pgffor}

% Set key for multicols in enumitem
\SetEnumitemKey{columns}{before=\begin{multicols}{#1},after=\end{multicols}}%

% Some definition
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{exercise}[theorem]{Exercise}

% from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/215571/7832
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\storedata}{mm}
  {
   \bcp_store_data:nn { #1 } { #2 }
  }

\NewDocumentCommand{\appenddata}{mm}
 {
  \bcp_append_data:nn { #1 } { #2 }
 }

\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand{\getdata}{O{1}m}
 {
  \bcp_get_data:nn { #1 } { #2 }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \bcp_store_data:nn #1 #2
 {
  % create the sequence if it doesn't exist or clear it if it exists
  \seq_if_exist:cTF { l_bcp_data_#1_seq }
   { \seq_new:c { l_bcp_data_#1_seq } }
   { \seq_clear:c { l_bcp_data_#1_seq } }
  % append the items
  \__bcp_append_data:nn { #1 } { #2 }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \bcp_append_data:nn #1 #2
 {
  % create the sequence if it doesn't exist, do nothing if it exists
  \seq_if_exist:cF { l_bcp_data_#1_seq }
   { \seq_new:c { l_bcp_data_#1_seq } }
  % append the items
  \__bcp_append_data:nn { #1 } { #2 }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \__bcp_append_data:nn #1 #2
 {
  % append items one at a time
  \tl_map_inline:nn { #2 }
   {
    \seq_put_right:cn { l_bcp_data_#1_seq } { ##1 }
   }
 }

\cs_new:Npn \bcp_get_data:nn #1 #2
 {
  % retrieve the requested item
  \seq_item:cn { l_bcp_data_#2_seq } { #1 }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

% Create a environment to encapsulate answer
\NewDocumentEnvironment{myenumerate}{m}{%
% Command to save answer
\NewDocumentCommand\sol{m}{%
    \appenddata{#1}{{##1}}% 
    }% close \sol
}%
{}% close myenumerate
\begin{document}
\section{Exercices}

\begin{exercise}
Factoring next expression:
\end{exercise}

\begin{myenumerate}{exe:1}
\begin{enumerate}
\item $a^{2}-b^{2}$ \sol{$\left(a-b\right)\left(a+b\right)$}
\item $x^{2}-2x+1$  \sol{$\left(x-1\right)^{2}$}
\item $3x+3y+3z$    \sol{$3x+3y+3z$}
\item $3x+3y-6z$    \sol{$3\left(x+y-2z\right)$}
\end{enumerate}
\end{myenumerate}

\begin{exercise}
Solve:
\end{exercise}

\begin{myenumerate}{exe:2}
\begin{enumerate}
\item $2x+3=5$ \sol{$1$}
\item $5x-2=7$ \sol{$\dfrac{9}{5}$}
\item $4-3x=5$ \sol{$-\dfrac{1}{3}$}
\end{enumerate}
\end{myenumerate}

\section{Answer}
% #1 : pass to tcolorbox
% #2 : name
% #3 : list
% #4 : maxvalue default: lenght of list
% #5 : columns
\DeclareTotalTColorBox{\answer}{O{} m m m O{4}}
{ colback=white,size=small,top=0mm,bottom=1.5mm, left=0mm,width=\columnwidth,title filled,%
  fontupper=\small,fonttitle=\small\sffamily,%
    adjusted title={#2},center title,#1}
  {% 
  \begin{enumerate}[columns=#5,leftmargin=15pt,labelsep=3pt,font=\footnotesize,nosep,widest=25,]%
  \small
  \setlength{\columnsep}{0pt} 
   \foreach \x in {1,...,#4} {
    \item \getdata[\x]{#3}%
    }
  \end{enumerate}
  }%
\answer{Exercise 1}{exe:1}{4}
\answer{Exercise 2}{exe:2}{3}[3]
\end{document}
```

Also try to add a key to `enumitem` to avoid writing a new environment

```
\SetEnumitemKey{reflist}{before=\storedata{#1}{}}%
```

But none of the options I tried worked out, so, here comes the big question:
How do I modify `\appendata|\storedata` to make them work globally?
`\appendata` would be like `\label` and `\getdata` would be as `\ref`, of course only with values and whitout `.aux` file (or two run).

Comment: Out of the blue: Have you tried `\seq_gput_right:Nn` instead of `\seq_put_right:Nn` etc, i.e. store it **g**lobally?

Comment: I have read the documentation, but it is very above my level :(

Comment: The `expl3` macros like `\seq_gput_right` or `\prop_gput` etc. store data in a global level, i.e. the data is still available outside of the group, i.e. the `g` prefix to `put` stands for `global`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to store the data globally, `\seq_gput_right:Nn` (and its variants) must be applied, otherwise the local saving gets lost ultimately after the group formed by the `enumerate` environment ends.

`\seq_put_right:Nn` however works only inside a group.

```
\documentclass{article}%
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{many}
\usepackage{pgffor}

% Set key for multicols in enumitem
\SetEnumitemKey{columns}{before=\begin{multicols}{#1},after=\end{multicols}}%

% Some definition
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{exercise}[theorem]{Exercise}

% from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/215571/7832
\ExplSyntaxOn

% Reporter macro, is expandable
\cs_new:Npn \reportnumberofseqitems #1{%
 \seq_count:c {l_bcp_data_#1_seq}%
}


\NewDocumentCommand{\storedata}{mm}
  {
   \bcp_store_data:nn { #1 } { #2 }
  }

\NewDocumentCommand{\appenddata}{mm}
 {
  \bcp_append_data:nn { #1 } { #2 }
 }

\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand{\getdata}{O{1}m}
 {
  \bcp_get_data:nn { #1 } { #2 }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \bcp_store_data:nn #1 #2
 {
  % create the sequence if it doesn't exist or clear it if it exists
  \seq_if_exist:cTF { l_bcp_data_#1_seq }
   { \seq_new:c { l_bcp_data_#1_seq } }
   { \seq_gclear:c { l_bcp_data_#1_seq } }
  % append the items
  \__bcp_append_data:nn { #1 } { #2 }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \bcp_append_data:nn #1 #2
 {
  % create the sequence if it doesn't exist, do nothing if it exists
  \seq_if_exist:cF { l_bcp_data_#1_seq }
   { \seq_new:c { l_bcp_data_#1_seq } }
  % append the items
  \__bcp_append_data:nn { #1 } { #2 }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \__bcp_append_data:nn #1 #2
 {
  % append items one at a time
  \tl_map_inline:nn { #2 }
   {
    \seq_gput_right:cn { l_bcp_data_#1_seq } { ##1 }
   }
 }

\cs_new:Npn \bcp_get_data:nn #1 #2
 {
  % retrieve the requested item
  \seq_item:cn { l_bcp_data_#2_seq } { #1 }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

% Create a environment to encapsulate answer
\NewDocumentEnvironment{myenumerate}{m}{%
% Command to save answer
\NewDocumentCommand\sol{m}{%
    \appenddata{#1}{{##1}}% 
    }% close \sol
}%
{}% close myenumerate
\begin{document}
\section{Exercices}

\begin{exercise}
Factoring next expression:
\end{exercise}

\begin{myenumerate}{exe:1}
\begin{enumerate}
\item $a^{2}-b^{2}$ \sol{$\left(a-b\right)\left(a+b\right)$}
\item $x^{2}-2x+1$  \sol{$\left(x-1\right)^{2}$}
\item $3x+3y+3z$    \sol{$3x+3y+3z$}
\item $3x+3y-6z$    \sol{$3\left(x+y-2z\right)$}
\end{enumerate}
\end{myenumerate}

\begin{exercise}
Solve:
\end{exercise}

\begin{myenumerate}{exe:2}
\begin{enumerate}
\item $2x+3=5$ \sol{$1$}
\item $5x-2=7$ \sol{$\dfrac{9}{5}$}
\item $4-3x=5$ \sol{$-\dfrac{1}{3}$}
\end{enumerate}
\end{myenumerate}

There are \reportnumberofseqitems{exe:1} items in exe:1 and     \reportnumberofseqitems{exe:2} items in exe:2

\section{Answer}
% #1 : pass to tcolorbox
% #2 : name
% #3 : list
% #4 : maxvalue default: lenght of list
% #5 : columns
\DeclareTotalTColorBox{\answer}{O{} m m m O{4}}
{ colback=white,size=small,top=0mm,bottom=1.5mm, left=0mm,width=\columnwidth,title filled,%
  fontupper=\small,fonttitle=\small\sffamily,%
    adjusted title={#2},center title,#1}
  {% 
  \begin{enumerate}[columns=#5,leftmargin=15pt,labelsep=3pt,font=\footnotesize,nosep,widest=25,]%
  \small
  \setlength{\columnsep}{0pt} 
   \foreach \x in {1,...,#4} {
    \item \getdata[\x]{#3}%
    }
  \end{enumerate}
  }%
\answer{Exercise 1}{exe:1}{4}
\answer{Exercise 2}{exe:2}{3}[3]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's just what I was looking for, a couple of cosnsults on the sidelines, how can I get the number of items on the list? (I would like to remove the mandatory `#4` from the foreach in `\answer`) and what is the maximum number of lists and the number of elements in this that they can have in a file? (If it is a large number that does not have memory problems, I will adapt this solution to another question)...Total thanks

Comment: @PabloGonzálezL: You can achieve the number of elements in the lists with the `\seq_count:N` macro, which is expandable. (similarly `\clist_count:N`, `\prop_count:N` ). Basically, the number of (global) lists is only limited by the number of registers for macro names, so unless you don't plan to have more then 30000 lists it should be alright. The amount of storage is only limited by memory.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, can you give me an example of how to use the list counter ?, in the forum I found https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/246924/7832 but in my case the lists are changing names and I can not use the same trick :(.

Comment: @PabloGonzálezL: With changing names you mean that you use something like `\seq_new:c {#1}` ?

Comment: OK, I understand, I'm a little lost with expl3 ... I'll try to make it work

Comment: @PabloGonzálezL: I've updated the example, see the `\reportnumberofseqitems` macro and the usage between the question and answer sections

Comment: A million thanks, it was just what I needed.....

Comment: @PabloGonzálezL: Happy TeXing! But in fact, you might return later on to `\labels` as soon as you want forward/backlinks, like I am doing in my not yet published package for questions and solutions

Comment: @Cristian Hupfer: In fact, the idea of using references in these cases is always good, this is the great idea I had in mind (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/363961/7832). I hope to see the new package soon (TexLive 2017 maybe?). Grateful again