# What is the limit of setting main_memory and pool_size in pdftex

Tags: pdftex, miktex, memory

I have a very big document (>50,000 pages), which I am trying to build. Unfortunately I am getting memory errors, therefore I tried to increase the memory.

While increasing the memory I encountered that I cannot increase the main_memory and pool_size indefinitely. Max limit for me is:

```
pool_size=40000000
main_memory=99999999
```

I have a 64bit windows OS with 32GB ram. Does anyone knows how to increase the memory beyond this limit or its not possible?

```
\documentclass[twoside]{book}

% Packages required by doxygen
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{doxygen}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox} % also loads graphicx
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{multirow}
\PassOptionsToPackage{warn}{textcomp}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[nointegrals]{wasysym}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

% Font selection
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[scaled=.90]{helvet}
\usepackage{courier}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\allsectionsfont{%
  \fontseries{bc}\selectfont%
  \color{darkgray}%
}
\renewcommand{\DoxyLabelFont}{%
  \fontseries{bc}\selectfont%
  \color{darkgray}%
}
\newcommand{\+}{\discretionary{\mbox{\scriptsize$\hookleftarrow$}}{}{}}

% Page & text layout
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{%
  letterpaper,%
  top=2.5cm,%
  bottom=2.5cm,%
  left=2.5cm,%
  right=2.5cm%
}
\tolerance=750
\hfuzz=15pt
\hbadness=750
\setlength{\emergencystretch}{15pt}
\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}
\setlength{\parskip}{3ex plus 2ex minus 2ex}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\paragraph}{%
  \@startsection{paragraph}{4}{0ex}{-1.0ex}{1.0ex}{%
    \normalfont\normalsize\bfseries\SS@parafont%
  }%
}
\renewcommand{\subparagraph}{%
  \@startsection{subparagraph}{5}{0ex}{-1.0ex}{1.0ex}{%
    \normalfont\normalsize\bfseries\SS@subparafont%
  }%
}
\makeatother

% Headers & footers
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancyplain}
\fancyhead[LE]{\fancyplain{}{\bfseries\thepage}}
\fancyhead[CE]{\fancyplain{}{}}
\fancyhead[RE]{\fancyplain{}{\bfseries\leftmark}}
\fancyhead[LO]{\fancyplain{}{\bfseries\rightmark}}
\fancyhead[CO]{\fancyplain{}{}}
\fancyhead[RO]{\fancyplain{}{\bfseries\thepage}}
\fancyfoot[LE]{\fancyplain{}{}}
\fancyfoot[CE]{\fancyplain{}{}}
\fancyfoot[RE]{\fancyplain{}{\bfseries\scriptsize Generated by Doxygen }}
\fancyfoot[LO]{\fancyplain{}{\bfseries\scriptsize Generated by Doxygen }}
\fancyfoot[CO]{\fancyplain{}{}}
\fancyfoot[RO]{\fancyplain{}{}}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{%
  \markboth{#1}{}%
}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{%
  \markright{\thesection\ #1}%
}

% Indices & bibliography
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
\makeindex

% Hyperlinks (required, but should be loaded last)
\usepackage{ifpdf}
\ifpdf
  \usepackage[pdftex,pagebackref=true]{hyperref}
\else
  \usepackage[ps2pdf,pagebackref=true]{hyperref}
\fi
\hypersetup{%
  colorlinks=true,%
  linkcolor=blue,%
  citecolor=blue,%
  unicode%
}

% Custom commands
\newcommand{\clearemptydoublepage}{%
  \newpage{\pagestyle{empty}\cleardoublepage}%
}

\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{labelsep=space,justification=centering,font={bf},singlelinecheck=off,skip=4pt,position=top}




%===== C O N T E N T S =====

\begin{document}

% Titlepage & ToC
\hypersetup{pageanchor=false,
             bookmarksnumbered=true,
             pdfencoding=unicode
            }
\pagenumbering{alph}
\begin{titlepage}
\vspace*{7cm}
\begin{center}%
{\Large D\+A\+S\+Y-\/uc }\\
\vspace*{1cm}
{\large Generated by Doxygen 1.8.12}\\
\end{center}
\end{titlepage}
\clearemptydoublepage
\pagenumbering{roman}
\tableofcontents
\clearemptydoublepage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\hypersetup{pageanchor=true}

%--- Begin generated contents ---
\chapter{abc}
\label{index}\hypertarget{index}{}\input{index}
\chapter{Test List}
\label{test}
\hypertarget{test}{}
\input{test}
\chapter{Todo List}
\label{todo}
\hypertarget{todo}{}
\input{todo}
\chapter{Bug List}
\label{bug}
\hypertarget{bug}{}
\input{bug}
\chapter{Module Index}
\input{modules}
\chapter{Namespace Index}
\input{namespaces}
\chapter{Hierarchical Index}
\input{hierarchy}
\chapter{Class Index}
\input{annotated}
\chapter{File Index}
\input{files}
\chapter{xyzDocumentation}
\input{aaaa}
\include{yyyy}
\include{xxx}
```

Comment: the number of pages has very little effect on memory use as the memory is recycled as each page is shipped out. You could of course try luatex which uses dynamic memory allocation, but you must have something very complicated on a single page? If it is tikz using up memory tikz externalize can help as you isiolate each tikzpicture into a separate run

Comment: The .tex files are generated by Doxygen after reading the code. I am not using tikz, but I have lot of graphics (pdf and md5 files). Just to give you a number doxygen is generating >6000 inputs and >1500 includes. Each include and input have graphic or nested inputs. Graphic is basically the class diagram generated by Doxygen. There are lot of cross-references in the document. Is that something that does not allow latex to recycle memory?

Comment: inputs includes and graphics in themselves don't have an impact on memory once pages are shipped out, obviously tex does have to store some global information. for cross referencing and the back end stores some global structures to finalize the pdf, but unless something is strange (for example you are building the entire document in a box then unboxing) nothing so far indicates why you are using so much memory.

Comment: I have entered the part of the code,so you can see the preamble. I have not included all include and inputs.

Comment: what happens if you use luatex instead of pdftex?

Comment: didnt tried luatex yet. I will try it

Answer (score 5):

You may be able to use luatex, which uses dynamic memory allocation, but for non-luatex the texlive 2017 texmf.cnf says:

```
% Memory. Must be less than 8,000,000 total.
%
% main_memory is relevant only to initex, extra_mem_* only to non-ini.
% Thus, have to redump the .fmt file after changing main_memory; to add
% to existing fmt files, increase extra_mem_*.  (To get an idea of how
% much, try \tracingstats=2 in your TeX source file;
% web2c/tests/memtest.tex might also be interesting.)
%
% To increase space for boxes (as might be needed by, e.g., PiCTeX),
% increase extra_mem_bot.
%
% For some xy-pic samples, you may need as much as 700000 words of memory.
% For the vast majority of documents, 60000 or less will do.
%
main_memory = 5000000 % words of inimemory available; also applies to inimf&mp
extra_mem_top = 0     % extra high memory for chars, tokens, etc.
extra_mem_bot = 0     % extra low memory for boxes, glue, breakpoints, etc.

% ConTeXt needs lots of memory.
extra_mem_top.context = 2000000
extra_mem_bot.context = 4000000
```

Note the first line.

However as noted in comments below the question, almost all memory is recycled as each page is  shipped out so unless you have  a logjam of floats taking all images to the end and so not releasing any memory, it is rather rare to ever get close to these limits.

Comment: It is easy to overflow pool-size. I managed to do it without problems with around 40 tikzpictures https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/316999/release-space-in-the-string-pool. ;-)

Comment: @UlrikeFischer you deserve no sympathy:-) But yes it would help if the OP showed the actual error message from TeX, I had assumed it was main mem that was running out, but pool size is rather different.

Answer (score 3):

As for `main_memory`, the maximum value has been

```
main_memory=12435455
```

for quite a while now (several TeXLive editions). To be found by bisection.

For MiKTeX the limit may be different.

After changing the value in the config file, the formats must be rebuilt in order to take effect.

---

Steps for TeXLive:

1. Run: `kpsewhich texmf.cnf` on the command line
2. In the file returned, change/add

   ```
   main_memory=12435455
   ```
3. Rebuild the format files:

   ```
   fmtutil-sys --all
   ```

---

Steps for MiKTeX, e. g. `pdflatex`:

1. `initexmf --edit-config-file=pdflatex`
2. change the value of `main_memory`
3. rebuild format: `initexmf --dump=pdflatex`

Repeat these steps for other engines/formats.

Comment: I can set main memory upto 99999999, which is larger than the number you have written. Am i missing something?

Comment: You can set any value in file `texmf.cnf`. However, to make it available, the format files must be rebuilt, using command `fmtutil-sys --byfmt latex` for example. Does it successfully exit (with status 0) using larger values?

Comment: The values I have mentioned in the question are valid (ie rebuild is successful). However, if I increase the value further it fails. I use initxemf --dump=pdftex

Comment: You certainly did not modify the correct `texmf.cnf` config file.

Comment: I am modifying pdftex.ini file. I cannot find any texmf.cnf in my installation. So i created one, but it seems I did something wrong. So I deleted it again.

Comment: It is `texmf.cnf`. See edited answer.

Comment: nothing happens when i write kpsewhich texmf.cnf on commnad line. (no file is returned)

Comment: Ok. Maybe TeXLive and MiKTeX differ in this regard.

Comment: pdftex.ini is a tex file you can not change the memory settings within tex?  I do not know where the miktex settings are so can not help with that. sorry. You can see the effective sizes on the last line of the log  where it shows memory use.

Comment: Sorry it was pdflatex not pdftex. This link shows how you can increase the memory. http://docs.miktex.org/manual/runtimeparams.html

Comment: @AlexG Yes, TexLive uses texm.cnf file. MikTex uses pdflatex.ini, latexmk.ini and so on.

Comment: Ok, I added the steps for MiKTeX for completeness. Now it is up to you to find the max. values (trial-and-error/bisection).