# miktex: forest tex capacity exceeded [save size=50000]

Tags: luatex

this is follows-up question to [forest tex capacity exceeded [save size=50000]](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/476642/) which receive two answers. both solve op problem with suggestion to upgrade op `latex` distribution to `texlive 2018`.

i test this (gaint) forest example with recent `miktex` (upgraded yesterday) and receive similar error:

```
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [save size=50000].
\pgf@process #1->{
                  #1\global \pgf@x =\pgf@x \global \pgf@y =\pgf@y }
l.982 \end{forest}

If you really absolutely need more capacity,
you can ask a wizard to enlarge me.

Here is how much of LuaTeX's memory you used:
 85529 strings out of 494300
 244514,1373583 words of node,token memory allocated 204422 words of node memory still in use:
   4591 hlist, 2 rule, 517 disc, 2 dir, 5492 glue, 668 kern, 6951 glyph, 11477 a
ttribute, 52 glue_spec, 11477 attribute_list, 1 temp, 27 if_stack, 1 write, 6882
 pdf_literal, 2 pdf_colorstack nodes
   avail lists: 1:9,2:79,3:18,4:1,5:12,6:6,7:17,8:1,9:8,10:1,12:1
 89047 multiletter control sequences out of 65536+200000
 26 fonts using 5681863 bytes
 184i,9n,190p,1590b,50000s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

how to convinced `miktex` to compile this [forest tex capacity exceeded [save size=80000]](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/476642/) document without error?

from `.log` file i coppy the following to lua related part:

```
This is LuaTeX, Version 1.09.2 (MiKTeX 2.9.6960 64-bit)  (format=lualatex 2019.2.26)  26 FEB 2019 14:07
 restricted system commands enabled.
**showframe-color.tex
(C:/Users/Zarko/Downloads/LaTeX-SE/SE-tests/showframe-color.tex
LaTeX2e <2018-12-01>
Lua module: luaotfload-main 2019-01-28 2.95 luaotfload entry point
Lua module: luaotfload-init 2019-01-28 2.95 luaotfload submodule / initializatio
n
Lua module: lualibs 2019-01-28 2.63 ConTeXt Lua standard libraries.
Lua module: lualibs-extended 2019-01-28 2.63 ConTeXt Lua libraries -- extended c
ollection.
Lua module: luaotfload-log 2019-01-28 2.95 luaotfload submodule / logging
Lua module: luaotfload-parsers 2019-01-28 2.95 luaotfload submodule / filelist
Lua module: luaotfload-configuration 2019-01-28 2.95 luaotfload submodule / conf
ig file reader
luaotfload | conf : Root cache directory is C:/Users/Zarko/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/
2.9/luatex-cache/generic/names.
luaotfload | init : Loading fontloader “fontloader-2019-01-28.lua” from kpse
-resolved path “C:/Users/Zarko/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/luatex/lu
aotfload/fontloader-2019-01-28.lua”.
Lua-only attribute luaotfload@state = 1
Lua-only attribute luaotfload@noligature = 2
Lua-only attribute luaotfload@syllabe = 3
luaotfload | init : Context OpenType loader version “3.107”
Inserting `luaotfload.node_processor' at position 1 in `pre_linebreak_filter'.
Inserting `luaotfload.node_processor' at position 1 in `hpack_filter'.
Lua module: luaotfload-loaders 2019-01-28 2.95 luaotfload submodule / callback h
andling
Inserting `luaotfload.define_font' at position 1 in `define_font'.
Lua module: luaotfload-database 2019-01-28 2.95 luaotfload submodule / database
Lua module: luaotfload-colors 2019-01-28 2.95 luaotfload submodule / color
Lua-only attribute luaotfload_color_attribute = 4
Lua module: luaotfload-resolvers 2019-01-28 2.95 luaotfload submodule / resolver
s
luaotfload | conf : Root cache directory is C:/Users/Zarko/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/
2.9/luatex-cache/generic/names.
Lua module: luaotfload-features 2019-01-28 2.95 luaotfload submodule / features
Lua module: luaotfload-letterspace 2019-01-28 2.95 luaotfload submodule / color
Lua module: luaotfload-auxiliary 2019-01-28 2.95 luaotfload submodule / auxiliar
y functions
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.set_sscale_dimens' at position 1 in `luaotfload.patch_
font'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.patch_cambria_domh' at position 2 in `luaotfload.patch
_font'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.fixup_fontdata' at position 1 in `luaotfload.patch_fon
t_unsafe'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.set_capheight' at position 3 in `luaotfload.patch_font
'.
Inserting `luaotfload.rewrite_fontname' at position 4 in `luaotfload.patch_font'
.
luaotfload | main : initialization completed in 1.477 seconds
```

Comment: miktex presumably? has some menu settings equivalent to texlive's texmf.cnf files?

Comment: this answer has miktex and texlive setting instructions (for main mem, but save stack size should be similar) https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/385852/what-is-the-limit-of-setting-main-memory-and-pool-size-in-pdftex

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, thank you for link. i will examine it asap.

Comment: MiKTeX will for several formats accept a command line value so before trying to find and edit the correct config file you could try from the terminal window bottom left of MiKTeX-console navigate (CD) to the working directory with the .tex then try out luatex  --save-size=80000 yourfilename.tex

Comment: @KJO and David Carlisle, i try to do what you suggest me in yours comments, but i went lost in this.  actually, i give up and will delete my question shortly.

Comment: Zarko it should be fairly easy to check if it is simply the need to increase the save size by running from the command line if you are only familiar with using your editor (you don't say how you run luatex) to compile then find your command and temporarily after the word luatex or LuaLaTeX add the extra option `--save-size=80000` with a space either side and see if that result is without error

Comment: Zarko I should have loaded the linked MWE first befor making rash statements IF I run as PDFLaTeX  I get the 50000 exceeded message but if I add -save-size=80000 to PdfLaTeX It will compile HOWEVER that command is not recognised by MiKTeX as an option for LuaLaTeX so you would need to find the location where LuaLaTeX can be configured to bump that memory item

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to increase the values in MiKTeX

For PdfLaTeX you can change your runtime compilation values by adding the additional option in your editor for example
 `pdfLaTeX -save-size=80000` *other options such as -shell-escape or -synctex= …*

However I was not able to use the same temporary setting on my editors LuaLaTeX  command line

I had to navigate to my config folder and it will be different for each user
it is **NOT the one in *texmfs\install\miktex\config***
  I use portable install so for me
**it is at texmfs\config\miktex\config** beware there are several files with the same name of LuaLaTeX.ini dotted around your system.

**It should be in the folder with about a dozen files**

> console.ini formats.ini languages.ini ... ... yap.ini

If you do not have a file called lualatex.ini then add it (if it has lots of contents it may be the wrong one so check against the adjoining files)

If you are happy it is the correct location then add this line `save_size=1000000`
and the compile should now work, it did for me.

P.S be patient, it does pause for a couple of minutes during compile due to the mass of data

Comment: thank you very much! i will try to manage this (again). i have miktex installed  for personal use, for editor i use winedt.