# Tex capacity exceeded [number of strings = 2078043]

Tags: luatex

Getting above error while compiling using lualatex for large PDF file (Approx. 50,000+ pages)

Please let me know which parameter to change in texmfapp.ini or any other file to deal with this error.

Getting this error after approx. 35,000 pages attached.

Comment: Didn't searching for :Tex capacity exceeded" on this site give any hints?

Comment: Got help with pool_size, main_memory and hash_extra...but now getting same error with number of string.

Comment: Now I'm curious: Exactly what use does a 50+k page PDF document have?

Comment: 50k pages sis a huge document, I think that with each possible settings you will run into limitations. Probably best to rethink have to structure the document. That said, I saw `-max-strings` in the configuration.

Comment: What to do depends a bit on why you run out of space. It can be bad code, see e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/316999/2388, then it would be better to correct the code. If you really need more string space: How to do it depends on your tex system but you didn't mention which one you use.

Comment: I am using miktex... in which I am compiling the code using lualatex

Comment: Then check the docu here https://docs.miktex.org/manual/texmfdefaults.html and https://docs.miktex.org/manual/texdefaults.html

Comment: A printed document of 1000 pages comes out at about 5cm thick. A printed document of 50,000 pages would then come out as a stack of paper about 2500 metres high. Best to divide your document into 50 thinner versions of 1000 pages each. I can't imagine anyone reading a 50,000 page pdf display.

Comment: @Peter Wilson I am ashamed of my arithmetic. I should have said that the stack of paper will be about 2.5 metres high; still a very significant pile.

Comment: @PeterWilson _I can't imagine anyone reading a 50,000 page pdf display._ I do that all the time. I browse the PDF it using table of content and having links everywhere. I do not see what the problem is. It takes 1 second to open such document on my PC. It is much better and faster than browsing it as web pages actually.